# Bluetooth multiple devices connection Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I'm trying to use two headphones A2DP to watch a movie.
I can connect the first headphone and everything works with audio.
I already use `paprefs`to configure virtual output and I can heard ok from on my first headphone and notebook output;
When I tried to connect the second headphone the bluetooth manager connect (and the headphone confirms the connection) but and quickly disconnect. Nothing happend after this.

I'm tried to use native Ubuntu 19.10 bluetooth manager, any error is showed

Using `blueman` shows an error

`D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.997" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file`

Then I tried to change the file in `etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and add

```
[General]

Enable = Source,Sink,Control,Media

AutoConnect = true

[Headset]

# Determine which headset profile to support i.e., HFP or HSP.
HFP = true

# Maximum number of headset connections to allow
MaxConnected = 3

[A2DP]

# Maximum number of A2DP connections to allow (source or sink)
MaxConnected = 3
```

Still same error. Someone can help me with this?